# Can a Non-Stationary ARIMA Series Be Simulated Using arima.sim in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am performing an experiment using classes of `ARIMA` models which I have to simulate for instance `AR`, `MA`, `ARMA` and possibly `ARIMA` using `arima.sim()` function in `R`. I am able to `AR`, `MA`, `ARMA` but `ARIMA` seems impossible as the coefficient of `AR` must be greater than 1 ($|\phi| > 1$) for the series to be non-stationary.

**When $|\varphi| < 1$**

Simulate AR(1) of 10 sample size with a coefficient of 0.8

```
# simulate ARIMA(1, 0, 0)
n <- 10
phi <- 0.8
set.seed(837530)
wn <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
ar1 <- sqrt((wn[1])^2/(1-phi^2))
for(i in 2:n){
  ar1[i] <- ar1[i - 1] * phi + wn[I]
}
```

Here the arithmetic of this expression $\varphi = \sqrt((\varepsilon _{1})^2/(1-\varphi^2))$ is valid in the sense that $\varphi = \sqrt(0.1309045/0.36)$ which is $\sqrt0.3636236$

**When $|\varphi| > 1$**

Simulate AR(1) of 10 sample size with a coefficient of 0.8

```
# simulate ARIMA(1, 0, 0)
n <- 10
phi <- 1.2
set.seed(837530)
wn <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
ar1 <- sqrt((wn[1])^2/(1-phi^2))

# Warning message:
#In sqrt((wn[1])^2/(1 - phi^2)) : NaNs produced

for(i in 2:n){
  ar1[i] <- ar1[i - 1] * phi + wn[I]
}
ar1
 #[1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Here the arithmetic of this expression $\varphi = \sqrt((\varepsilon _{1})^2/(1-\varphi^2))$ is not valid in the sense that $\varphi = \sqrt(0.1309045/-0.44)$ which is $\sqrt-0.2975102$

**Similar experiment is performed using `arima.sim()` function**

**When $|\varphi| < 1$**

```
set.seed(837530)
ma1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = c(0.8), order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
```

No error message

**When $|\varphi| > 1$**

```
set.seed(837530)
ma1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = c(1.2), order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
#Error in arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = c(1.2), order = c(1, 0, 0)),  : 
  #'ar' part of model is not stationary
```

**What I want to know**

Can it be said that a non-stationary series can **not** be simulated using `arima.sim`?

Comment: The problem is in your calculations:  In the second block, `ar1` is `NaN` because `1-phi^2` is negative.   I'm not sure what you're trying to calculate there, but it looks like the formula you are using is meant for stationary series.  Fix that entry and the rest will work.  The `arima.sim` function assumes the AR part of the model is stationary, so it won't work for you.

Comment: 1 - (1+) value will always be negative value, the reason why it is not stationary even in `arima.sim()` function

Comment: My point was that you shouldn't be using that formula on a non-stationary AR series.

Comment: Ok, tell me what to use and why I'm using such?

Comment: Remember,  the formula that I use is the variance of AR(1) model which should be the starting point of the series.

Comment: I think `arima.sim()` function is using similar starting point as its algorithm.

Comment: If it is not stationary, the variance blows up with successive observations. You can start at any finite value, and as the simulation progresses, you'll get larger and larger values.  I'd start with 0.

Comment: This your idea sounds good but I don't think is an acceptable standard for the simulation of  ARIMA series. The  Randomly generated numbers is important for the series simulation so also its starting point.

Comment: The random number in the ARIMA series simulation follows a number distribution with mean 0 and variance of 1. Not only that, it has a starting point for every class of the series which is usually the variance of the series.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to start a *nonstationary* series with its variance, because such a series doesn't have a variance.  Start your series with any number you like.

Comment: Clearly, you can simulate a nonstationary series in R. But I suppose your question is specifically about simulation using the function `arima.sim`. I have edited your post to reflect that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `stats::arima.sim` to simulate from an ARIMA process where the AR part implies nonstationary behavior; it gives an error that explicitly states that this is not supported by this function. You *can* have unit roots (specified in the difference part, not the AR part) however, so there exist nonstationary ARIMA processes which it can simulate.

`arima.sim` does *not* prevent this situation because of what you mention concerning $\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}$ leading to a negative variance: it does *not* start from a draw from the distribution $X_0 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}\right)$  by default, it starts from $X_0 = 0$ instead, so this wouldn't matter.

The only reason I see for why `arima.sim` would choose not to support such ARIMA models is that it uses a rule of thumb to automatically determine an appropriate burn-in period at the beginning of simulation:

```
n.start <- p + q + ifelse(p > 0, ceiling(6/log(minroots)),  0)
```

`minroots` is the smallest norm of the roots of the characteristic polynomial. In the AR(1) case, this is just $|1/\phi|$, which would lead to a negative burn-in if it's less than 1. It of course doesn't make sense to even compute a burn-in period in a situation where $|\phi| > 1$, since the purpose of such a thing is to take a process that isn't stationary but that converges to one asymptotically, and crudely discard the first few steps so that what's left is closer in behavior to the stationary distribution. `arima.sim` could probably simply set the burn-in to zero in that case, but it doesn't. I wouldn't expect much support to change this behavior considering that what you're trying to do is 1) trivial to do by hand, 2) unlikely to be widely useful to other people and 3) a change to a function that is part of a core package.

The "meaning" of drawing $X_0 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}\right)$ is that, when $|\phi|<1$, this is the stationary distribution of the process: if you start from this distribution, then $X_t$ will have this same distribution at all $t$. If $|\phi|<1$ and you start from another distribution, there is a long-run distribution which you reach asymptotically and which is identical to the stationary distribution (you could use a burn-in period to sample it approximately). However, when $|\phi| > 1$, there is *no* stationary distribution, the process does not converge to any such distribution in the long-run, and there is no particular reason to start from any distribution; you have to specify it as part of your model.

Comment: I am much interested in your answer for it speaks the language of my problem. I want to be sure of your response to my question: Can it be said that a non-stationary series can not be simulated using `arima.sim()`? I need a yes or a no response

Comment: @DanielJames The way you're phrasing that is ambiguous. There are non-stationary ARIMA processes which can't be simulated with `stats::arima.sim`. There are also non-stationary ARIMA processes which can be simulated with `stats::arima.sim`.

Comment: Can you please give me `examples in `R` for each case (There are non-stationary ARIMA processes that can't be simulated with stats::arima.sim. There are also non-stationary ARIMA processes that can be simulated with stats::arima.sim).

Comment: @DanielJames As you pointed out, `arima.sim(list(ar=1.2), 100)` is not stationary and returns an error. On the other hand, `arima.sim(list(order = c(0,1,0)), 100)` isn't stationary and doesn't return an error. Because of how initialization is handled, `arima.sim(list(ar=0.8), 100)` isn't technically stationary either (only approximately in the long run), and does work.

Comment: From these examples you have given to me, I can conclude that stationary `AR` or `ARIMA` of whichever order can't be simulated using `arima.sim()` function. I am afraid that you do not want to state that categorically.

Comment: No, you can't conclude that, and it isn't true (it's also the opposite of the question you asked). For example, `arima.sim(list(ma=0.7), 100)` is stationary (because the burn-in works exactly when $p=d=0$). You can get exactly stationary AR(1) processes with $|\phi|<1$ by supplying the initial innovation with the correct distribution, as well, for example: `arima.sim(list(ar=0.8), n.start = 1, start.innov = rnorm(1, sd = 1/sqrt(1-0.8^2)),100)`. If you don't, the approximate stationarity after the burn-in period is still typically sufficient in practice.

Comment: All your examples are focused on how to simulate ARIMA that is stationary and also has AR coefficient that is less than 1. Can you Please show me an example of a non-stationary series that has an AR coefficient that is greater than 1?

Comment: The second example in your question would be such an example if it started from any distribution at all (including degenerate ones like just starting from `ar1[1]=0`), but it doesn't because you're taking the square root of a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate stationary ARMA models using the `rGARMA` function in the [`ts.extend` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ts.extend).  If you want to extend this to ARIMA models then all you have to do is to simulate the ARMA model and then add the required number of differencing steps.  Extensions to non-stationary time-series processes with explosive roots can be done, but it requires specification of starting points for the series.

Comment: Show some examples please.