# ARIMA(1, 1, 0) and explosive process

Tags: arima, unit-root

What is the difference between ARIMA(1, 1, 0) whose AR coefficient is smaller than 1 (e.g. 0.3) after being differenced and an explosive process whose AR coefficient is 1.3? Are these two identical? They are identical at least mathematically (Yt = Yt-1 + 0.3Yt-1 = (1 + 0.3) Yt-1 = 1.3Yt-1), but I think they behave differently. How can we differentiate these two?

Answer (score 0):

The two processes are not identical. Your ARIMA(1,1,0) is $BY_t=0.3BY_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, using the backshift operator $BY_t=Y_t-Y_{t-1}$, or $Y_t=1.3Y_{t-1}-0.3Y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$, and the AR(1) is just $Y_t=1.3Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, without a $Y_{t-2}$ term.

This implies that the second model indeed explodes. For instance, if I try to simulate it using R's `arima.sim()`, I get an error: [Can a Non-Stationary ARIMA Series Be Simulated Using arima.sim in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/565118/1352) In contrast, your ARIMA(1,1,0) model yields well-behaved time series that do not explode.

Here are 20 simulations for your ARIMA(1,1,0) model:

[image: ARIMA(1,1,0) simulations]

Compare to 20 simulations for your nonstationary AR(1) model:

[image: nonstationary AR(1) simulations]

R code:

```
n_rows <- 5
n_cols <- 4

nn <- 100
n_burnin <- 1000

opar <- par(mfrow=c(n_rows,n_cols),mai=c(.5,.5,.1,.1),las=1)
    for ( ii in 1:(n_rows*n_cols) ) {
        set.seed(ii)    # for reproducibility
        plot(arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.3,order=c(1,1,0)),n=nn,n.start=n_burnin),
            xlab="",ylab="")
    }

    for ( ii in 1:(n_rows*n_cols) ) {
        set.seed(ii)    # for reproducibility
        innovations <- rnorm(nn+n_burnin)
        series <- ts(c(0,rep(NA,nn+n_burnin)))
        for ( ii in 1:(nn+n_burnin) ) {
            series[ii+1] <- 1.3*series[ii]+innovations[ii]
        }
        plot(ts(tail(series,nn)),xlab="",ylab="")
    }
par(opar)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think my model for a time series with a unit root and a stationary AR process is inaccurate. Yt = Yt-1 + 0.3Yt-1 is indeed explosive, and a time series with a unit root and a stationary AR process will be Yt = Yt-1 + Ut, where Ut (first differenced Yt) = 0.3Ut-1.